# elasticsearch.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04

i installed elasticsearch on a vps as explained [here](https://tecadmin.net/setup-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu/). But now its not running and when i run `systemctl status elasticsearch`, the active status is a red failed.

These are the error messages:

> elasticsearch.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted.
>
> Started Elasticsearch.
>
> Failed to attach 20579 to compat systemd cgroup /system.slice/elasticsearch.service: No such file or directory.
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>
> elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a.
>
> elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Before this, the status was green but all requests to port 9200 would error out with connection refused. Until I realized the vps had only 1 GB of ram but Xms and Xmx in the jvm.options file where set to 1 GB. So I brought those down to 512m(i edited `-Xms1g` and `-Xmx1g` to `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx512m`, that's the correct syntax, right?).

And these are the only uncommented lines in elasticsearch.yml:

> path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
>
> path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
>
> network.host: 0.0.0.0
>
> cluster.name: "raha"

I only added network.host and cluster.name.

We used to have someone in our company that had a habit of playing with user permissions in our servers. I think that may be an issue. But I have no way of finding that out. Does it help if I ask the hosting company to restore the vps to the default configurations? Is there any other suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: It seems related to [this systemd issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74804457/4970442)

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`, modify the settings under **discovery** as follows:

```
# ——————————— Discovery ———————————
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is [“127.0.0.1”, “[::1]”]
discovery.seed_hosts: [“host_name_you_choose”]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
cluster.initial_master_nodes: [“name_of_your_node”]
```

It's necessary to bootstrap the ElasticSearch implementation for the first usage as referenced here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html